# Matching whole word that includes a dollar sign?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently using

```
string pattern = "\\b" + myString + "\\b"
```

which matches the string just fine, but now I need to find the string with a `$` prefixed to it, so I need to match `$myString` now when it's encased within brackets like `[$myString]`.  How can I add a dollar sign to my pattern without Regex thinking it's a special character for some Regex settings?

Comment: are you trying to find currency? or just words with `$` in the front of them?

Comment: Just words like "This is an example of $myString", I'd want it to pick up on the "$myString"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex

```
\[\$myString]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JopyJK7TCKblt-Et)

**C#**

```
string pattern = @"\[\$" + myString + @"]";
```

**Description**

```
\[\$myString]
    \[ matches the character [ literally
    \$ matches the character $ literally
    myString matches the characters myString literally (case sensitive)
    ] matches the character ] literally
```

Comment: You don't really need word boundaries anymore, since you enclosed the string in square brackets. Also the second bracket doesn't need escaping, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240997/escaping-closing-braces#answer-8242044

Comment: @Robin agreed, i overlooked that unless the regex gets more complex then the `\]` might need to be there but right now it doesn't.  Also the word boundary isn't serving much of a purpose.  Might need OP to see if it is okay that these might match no space separated items.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to escape the `$`, if you need to use it as a dollar symbol. **However**, this means you can't use word boundaries to see the, well, word boundary. If your pattern is that fixed, why don't you just do something like:

```
string pattern = "\\[\\$" + myString + "]"
```

Comment: I'm trying isMatch on the string "[$myString]" with the above pattern, but it keeps returning false. Any idea why?

Comment: You can't use `\b`, word boundary, to delimit a non alphanumerical string. Just like it wouldn't match the position between two successive space characters, it won't match the position between `[` and `$` :/

Comment: Oh drats, do you know of a specific pattern I could use to match "$myString" when it's encased in brackets?

Comment: @Smoore `\[\$\bmyString\b\]` just change it to this

Comment: @Robin your current answer doesn't even work for $myString because of the symbol statement you already made please update it to the above.

Comment: @abc123: You're right. Seemingly obvious answer, there was actually a subtlety. Thx

Answer (score 3):

There are two options; either you escape it, or put it in a character class, that is:

```
\$
```

or

```
[$]
```

I prefer the former. And since you're in C#, you can use the `@` symbol so that you don't have to double escape things:

```
string pattern = @"\$\b" + myString + @"\b"
```

With this, you should be able to match `$myString`

---

As per your edit, if you want to match square parentheses too, just add them, but don't forget escaping!

```
string pattern = @"\[\$\b" + myString + @"\b\]"
```

Except that since the first `[` is escaped, you don't actually need to escape the second, since you cannot have a character class (`[ ... ]`) with no opening `[`:

```
string pattern = @"\[\$\b" + myString + @"\b]"
```